# Meta_query not filtering posts

Tags: custom-field, query, meta-query

I'm trying to filter out 'properties' on a page based on whether they are vacation or long-term rentals. Right now, the results of the following query displays all properties, not just either vacation or just long-term rentals. Am I missing something super obvious?

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'rental_type',
                'value' => 'Vacation'
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => $properties_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you certain your post_type and key names are correct?

Comment: positive, everything else is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use meta_query.

Simply use the code like shown below:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'meta_key' => 'rental_type',
        'meta_value' => 'Vacation'
        'posts_per_page' => $properties_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
```

Also you got to get the value of $properties_per_page before this query.